# Angular 6 : ERROR Error: Argument non valide while insert

Tags: html, angular

While working with angular6, i have a form that i want to submit to insert an object with some fields.

HTML code:

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid" #f="ngForm" validate>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">book Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           [(ngModel)]="book.libelle"
           #libelle="ngModel"  
           minlength="4" 
           required  
           class="form-control"
           id="libelle" 
           name="libelle">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
  <button type="submit"  
         class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
         (click)="saveBook(book)" 
         prevent-double-submit>
    <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> save
  </button>      
</div>
```

In my book model the field is named lebelle.

ts piece of for insert :

```
 public saveBook(newBook:Book) {
   return this.bookService.saveBookService(this.book)
     .subscribe((reponseService: ReponseService) => {
    this.reponseService = new ReponseService(reponseService);
    this.messageErreur = new MessageErreur(this.reponseService.recupererMessageErreur());
    if (this.messageErreur.contientErreur()) {
      this.alertStyle = Constantes.ALERT_PRIMARY_RED;
    } else {
      this.alertStyle = Constantes.ALERT_PRIMARY_GREEN;
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/BaseUrl?messageErreur.code=" + this.messageErreur.code + "&messageErreur.message=" + this.messageErreur.message + "&alertStyle=" + this.alertStyle);
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: add code fot .html and .ts file in your question?

Comment: i've added more details for my html page

Comment: file .ts added.

Comment: what is error add it.

Comment: ERROR Error: Argument non valide. book name   : java book

Comment: as you are not creating a new variable member in html, so you can just use `(click)="saveBook()" `, and can access `this.book` in the `saveBook() ` method.